# You are a Genius

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

*Apologize the words that I selected, but it's the example that I have.*

I'm a bit confused about "You", plural and singular use cases.

```
"You are a Genius" - singular
"You sucks" - ????
```

Here, I guess, there are an extra corporal expression that completes the statement. Looking into my eyes, singular. Opening his arms, plural.

In Spanish is totally different.

```
"Sos un genio" - singular
"Sos idiota" - singular
"Son idiotas" - plural
```

What i missing? how to distinguish between "you" as plural or singular in a chat, specifically in a chat room.

Comment: There is no distinction in English. You must infer what is meant from gesture, as you say, or from context.

Comment: It would be “you suck” (not “you sucks”) whether you were talking to one person or several, though.

Comment: I am confused as to _what_ you are asking. You give two examples, one of which is simply not correct English. Then you talk about _I_ and _he_, which have nothing to do with _you_. If your question is just your last line, I do not really see the relevance of (especially) the first part of your question.

Comment: @oerkelens *Looking into my eyes, singular. Opening his arms, plural.* both are not examples, just clarification of *extra corporal expression*

Answer (score 6):

In a chat room, people would probably use extra words to be more clear. Some examples:

> You all suck. (Referring to everyone.)
>
> You both suck. (Referring to two people.)
>
> Adam, you suck. (Referring to Adam by himself.)

"You suck" by itself is usually singular. Sometimes it's really not clear what someone meant, so you can always ask who sucks.

With "you are", you can tell whether it's singular or plural by the noun. "You are a genius" is singular because "a genius" is singular. "You are geniuses" is plural because "geniuses" is plural. Of course, you can also use extra words, just like with "you suck".

Answer (score 1):

You are a good person.
You ate my apple.
You are a genius.

These are singular.

You are **all** good people.
You **guys** ate my apple.
You are a very smart **group**.

It's usually what follows the 'you' that identifies as singular or plural.